# Durable Trekking Boots (vegan)

Tags: veganism, clothing, leather, sports, travel

Where can I find a pair of durable vegan boots for trekking?

I'm specifically looking for a goodyear-welted boot, so that they are heavy, durable, and I can take them to any-old boot shop to have them resoled for years to come.

Are there any manufacturers of all-vegan boots that are built to last years of abuse on the trails? I'm not interested in this lightweight material with custom-fit soles that will need to be replaced in 1-3 years.

Comment: See also https://old.reddit.com/r/goodyearwelt/comments/4bomih/fauxleather_shoes_that_are_wellmade_and_goodyear/

Comment: See https://www.avesuveganshoes.com/vegan-mens-shoes/boots-com.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Quality Material Matters

There are many vegan shoes on the market that use a goodyear welt, but wheather or not they are durable is dubious.

As it was [mentioned on /r/goodyearwelt](https://old.reddit.com/r/goodyearwelt/comments/4bomih/fauxleather_shoes_that_are_wellmade_and_goodyear/), a GYW design only makes sense if the boot's upper is durable enough to outlive the sole. Many cheap faux leathers will crack and fall apart with wear in a short time, but [high-quality faux leathers actually last *longer*](https://www.mercedes-market.com/2017/12/27/mb-tex-interior-mercedes-benz-interior-materials-explained/) than the animal skin leather. Unfortunately, [it's not trivial to differentiate between high- & low-quality faux leathers](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/1941/4031), so it's best to go by brand, reviews, and reputation.

## Brands

That said, here's some brands that make vegan shoes with a goodyear welted sole.

### Vegetarian Shoes

[image: vegetarian Shoes Airseal Boulder]

[Vegetarian Shoes](https://www.vegetarian-shoes.co.uk/) is an all-vegan shoe brand. They claim that their boots are extremely durable and made with the highest quality materials; they specifically advertise their goodyear welt build where applicable.

Examples of vegan, goodyear welted boots from vegetarian shoes include their [various Airseal models](https://www.vegetarian-shoes.co.uk/airseal/__airseal_boots/10021_0c.html).

I found a [very good review](http://www.veganshoeaddict.com/vegan-boots/those-famous-vegan-boots-that-look-like-doc-martens-or-grinders) made 7 years after someone who bought the airseal boots and abused them at festivals, burning man, trekking, etc.

[image: Veggie Trekkers]

They also have non-goodyear-welt trekking boot models [Veggie Trekker MK5](https://www.vegetarian-shoes.co.uk/unisex/veggie_trekker_mk5_black/18001_p.html) and the [Snowdon Boot](https://www.vegetarian-shoes.co.uk/unisex/snowdon_boot_black/11534_p.html). But they specifically mention in the product's description that the dual-density vibram sole makes the boot easier to resole.

I found [another great review](https://veganoutdooradventures.com/vegetarian-shoes-vegan-hiking-boot-review/) made 5 years after someone who bought the veggie trekker boots and abused them on a lot of hiking trails.

### Dr Martens

This is a classic boot that has a noticeable off-color thread in their goodyear welt. Popular among punks, this is more of a boot for style than trekking.

Their boots are traditionally leather, but they [now offer vegan models](https://www.drmartens.com/us/en/unisex/vegan-footwear-and-accessories/c/04060000). Unfortunately, top reviews on Amazon suggest that they fall apart after a few months.

Examples of vegan, goodyear welted boosts from Dr Martens includes the model 1460 and 190.

### NAE

[NAE](https://www.nae-vegan.com/en/brand/about-us_589.html) (which stands for No Animal Exploitation) is an all-vegan shoe brand based in Portugal.

I could not find any a first-hand accounts from consumers who bought NAE boots and later wrote a review describing if/how they held up to years of trail abuse.

Examples of vegan, goodyear welted boots from NAE include their models Andre, Atka, and Etna.

### NOAH

[NOAH](https://www.noah-shop.com/en/vegan-shoes/vegan-mens-shoes/boots/) is another all-vegan shoe brand that's been around since 2009.

I could not find any a first-hand accounts from consumers who bought NOAH boots and later wrote a review describing if/how they held up to years of trail abuse.

Examples of vegan, goodyear welted boots from NOAH include their models Claudia & Claudio and Claude.

Comment: Are all of these vegan leathers made of plastic?